# DateTime System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, исключения, datetime

Используется API библиотека.
При запуске выдаёт System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
Exception ловится именно при указании Created, вне зависимости от порядка.
По документации, обязательными являются FromExclusive и ToExclusive.
Формат данных - DateTime

Просьба подсказать, в чём ошибка

```
 private static DocumentClass[] DocInfoSearch(IComClient servClient)
    {
        long auchanID = 5675;
        var dt = DateTime.Today.Date;
        //параметры поиска
        var documentFilter = new DocumentSearchArguments();
        documentFilter.Created.From = dt.AddDays(-1);
        documentFilter.Created.To = dt;
        documentFilter.SecondCompanyId = auchanID;
        documentFilter.StatusForSenderId = 19;
        documentFilter.Created.FromExclusive = false;
        documentFilter.Created.ToExclusive = false;
        //поиск и запись результатов в переменную
        var results = servClient.SearchDocumentsByParams(documentFilter);
```

Comment: У вас Created null, где вы его устанавливаете? `documentFilter.Created = new Foo();`

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло добавление documentFilter.Created = new DateRange();